# How to access Docker Swarm service from outside the cluster?

Tags: docker

If there is a web app running in my cluster, how do I access it from an external client? Do I need a reverse proxy or is there a "swarm way" of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your service you need to use the `--publish` option.

E.g.:

```
docker service create --detach=true --replicas 3 --publish 80:80 --name httpd httpd
```

Now port 80 is exposed to the main network. Usefully, *every* server in the swarm publishes port 80 and will do an internal redirect to wherever the container is actually running.

Similarly, if you use a stack then you use the `ports` option. E.g.:

```
services:
  web:
    image: httpd
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Comment: How would that look like in a docker-compose file?